# Upload data to the db without stopping the loading of the site

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a small problem, I created a data analysis system on my site. Everything works, only that every time I run the post to be able to insert the data in the db, it slows down the loading of the site a lot. I was wondering if it was possible to load the data in the database without stopping the execution of the site. For example, if I load and click on an item in the menu I would like it not to let me wait for the data to be entered in the db but to continue with the click I made on the menu item.

My code works this way.

I take the data that interest me with javascript and I post to a php page for data entry

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using AJAX calls to pass the value from frontend to PHP. 
If not, try to use AJAX calls calling the PHP page for data entry and passing the values you want to store. AJAX calls are asynchronous so JavaScript does not have to wait for the server response.

This is an example of AJAX call:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "data_entry.php?value1=exampleOfValueBeingStored1&value2=exampleOfValueBeingStored2", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

in the REST paradigm if you need to update values you should use PUT or POST instead of GET. GET should be used only when you want retrieve values already inserted inside database for example.

Comment: Thanks Wolfetto, I tried to use your code, but time is always too long, 7 seconds before loading the page...

Comment: There are something wrong in your code. You have to change the logic of your application. The key is that, you load the page and after that use ajax calls to store the data inside database according to user interaction. In this scenario you are not waiting for store procedure because it works in parallel (asynchronous).